# M.L.E. of binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have two questions.

1)  In maximum likelihood estimation of binomial distribution I did as follows :
 $L(p)=$$\prod$$ n\choose  x_i $$p^{xi}(1-p)^{n-x_i}$
=$ n\choose  x_1 $$n\choose  x_2 $...$ n\choose  x_n $ $p^{\sum x_i}(1-p)^{(n-x_1)+(n-x_2)+...(n-x_n)}$.

My question isn't $(1-p)^{(n-x_1)+(n-x_2)+...(n-x_n)}=(1-p)^{n^2-\sum x_i}$.

Then the M.L.E I get is =$\bar x\over n$  .
Is this wrong?

The article [here](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/MLE_Examples:_Binomial_and_Poisson_Distributions_OldKiwi) says $\hat{p}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_{i}}{n}=\frac{k}{n}$.

Here why is it written as $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_{i}}{n}$ and **not** as $\bar x$. ?

2)Here does  ${\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_{i}}$ refer to the number of successes in n independent trials?
What is meant by **number of successes in n independent trials**?

```
> y<-rbinom(20,20,0.4)
> y
 [1] 11  3  5  8 10  9  6 11  7  9  8  5  6  6  6  9  8 10  4  7
> x<-sum(y)
> x
[1] 148
```

Does it mean if I generate some random numbers as then `rbinom` gives the number of successes in each trial so 
 ${\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_{i}}$  refers to sum of `rbinom` values. Is the way I have understood  ${\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x}_{i}}$  correct ?

Comment: In 1), you are confusing $n$ the size of the sample with $n$ the parameter of the binomial distribution $(n,p)$. Note that the reference you give is interested in *Bernoulli* samples, not binomial ones (and, to them, $n$ is simply the size of the sample).

Comment: @Did  Thank You. Can you please tell me, when it says `number of successes in n independent trials` does it mean the sum of all successes in each independent trial.

Comment: As I said, there is probably a deep confusion at work here, between binomial distributions and Bernoulli distributions. To count the number of successive trials amongst $n$ independent trials, use one random variable with binomial distribution $(n,p)$. The likelihood $L(p)$ for the independent repetition of $k$ of these steps, for the results $x_1$, ..., $x_k$, where each $x_i$ is an integer between $0$ and $n$, is $$L(p)=\prod_{i=1}^k{n\choose x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}\propto p^{s_k}(1-p)^{nk-s_k}\qquad s_k=\sum_{i=1}^kx_i,$$ which yields $$\hat p=\frac{s_n}{nk}.$$

Comment: @Did  if `x` is the number of successes in n independent trials then the given answer is $x/n$. In this case is it repeated only once. That is, is k=1

Comment: I don't understand the difference of trial and `k` repetitions. For example tossing a coin 20 times to see how many tails occur, in that case no.of trials=20 right? what is k here?